# Excessive memory use with unicode-math/Fira Sans and xfrac

Tags: fonts, luatex, unicode-math, performance, xfrac

When trying to use the Greek symbols in the font Fira Sans with `unicode-math`, I noticed that running `lualatex` on my document uses up enormous amounts of RAM. I have distilled my problem to a minimal working example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{latinmodern-math.otf}
% each of the following \setmathfont lines adds around 1GB of used RAM
\setmathfont{FiraSans-Regular.otf}[range=up/{greek,Greek}]
\setmathfont{FiraSans-Italic.otf}[range=it/{greek,Greek}]
\setmathfont{FiraSans-Bold.otf}[range=bfup/{greek,Greek}]
\setmathfont{FiraSans-BoldItalic.otf}[range=bfit/{greek,Greek}]
\usepackage{xfrac}

\begin{document}

$\sfrac{1}{2}$

\end{document}
```

Running this with `lualatex` uses around 4GB of memory (and takes a quite while to complete). For longer documents, this grows even more, eventually filling all the RAM I have available.

I have noticed that when running this, execution seems to take a lot of time during the following part of the output (during which memory usage increases continuously):

> ```
> (load luc: ~/.texlive2018/texmf-var/luatex-cache/generic/fonts/otl/lmroman7-regular.luc)
> (load luc: ~/.texlive2018/texmf-var/luatex-cache/generic/fonts/otl/lmroman5-regular.luc)
> ```

`xelatex` handles the same example in a fraction of a second and without unexpected use of memory (maybe not surprising, since the lines above are related to `luatex`’s font cache).

What is going on here and can I do anything about it? This doesn’t seem to happen with fonts other than Fira Sans.

---

I’m running TeX Live from the Ubuntu 18.10 repositories (“This is LuaTeX, Version 1.07.0 (TeX Live 2019/dev/Debian)”).

Comment: It works okay, if I use `\setmathfont{FiraMath}` instead of text fonts.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Well, yes, but Fira Math is very young. The question is more about an explanation for the behavior (maybe it’s a bug that’s worth fixing?), not workarounds.

Comment: I don't know what happens or if xfrac is actually meant to be used together with unicode math. I suggest that you report it at the unicode github https://github.com/wspr/unicode-math/issues. Will will perhaps know something about it.